# Docker-Compose File Invalid

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I am using Docker and Docker-compose for the first time and I am getting this Error `ERROR: The Compose file is invalid because: Service volumes have neither an image nor a build context specified. At least one must be provided.` but my docker-compose file has a build context specified. I tried moving the `build context` around different places but still no headway. Here is my docker-compose file

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  express:
    container_name: express
    image: node:12-alpine
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./
        target: /app
      - type: volume
        source: nodemodules
        target: /app/node_modules
        volume:
          nocopy: true
    build: .
    working_dir: /app
    command: npm run dev
    ports:
      - '4000:4000'
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - PORT=4000
  volumes:
  nodemodules:
    links:
      - mongo
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data/db
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
      - '27018:27018'
      - '27019:27019'
```

What exactly could I be doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: The lines that say `volumes:` and `nodemodules:` are indented at the same level as other services, but are empty.  You probably want to delete these lines.

Comment: @King Etiosasere did you try David's Maze suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

As @DavidMaze wrote:

The lines called `volumes:` and `nodemodules:` are wrong indented. They are at the same level as other services, but are empty. You probably want to delete these lines.

Take a look: [docker-compose-file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it after some days of googling. Apparently, all I had to do was to put

```
volumes:
  nodemodules:
```

exactly like that at the last lines of the file and remove them from the `services` mapping. So my file became like this at the end of the day.

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  express:
    container_name: express
    image: node:12-alpine
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./
        target: /app
      - type: volume
        source: nodemodules
        target: /app/node_modules
        volume:
          nocopy: true
    build: .
    working_dir: /app
    command: npm run dev
    ports:
      - '4000:4000'
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - PORT=4000
    links:
      - mongo
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data/db
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
      - '27018:27018'
      - '27019:27019'
volumes:
 nodemodules:
```